# WCF client not working after add a customer binding endpoint to the same ServiceHost

Tags: wcf, extend, netnamedpipebinding

1. extend WCF stuff hosting a NamedPipeServerStream to support communication with nodejs, it works if open a new ServerHost with endpoint "`net.jsonpipe://localhost/JasonService`".
2. a workable ServerHost with endpoint "`net.pipe://localhost/MyService`", everything is fine with a proxy , c# client `DuplexClientBase`.
3. once i open these two endpoints in one ServerHost, the c# client not working any more.
   with WCF TRACE, i see an exception `There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)` when TransportSend.

anyone has any clue for help?

thanks in advance

Comment: it turns out to be an `Serialize/Deserialize`  issue on Transport level, once enable any custom formatter for endpoint DispatchOperation in server side, should enable it too for  endponit ClientOperation from client side

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on `Trace` for detailed error information in this case to locate the cause. You can view the following links on how to configure Trace here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

The problem could be a serialization issue or it could be related to the [transport mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/streaming-message-transfer?redirectedfrom=MSDN)(try changing the transfer mode from buffered to streamed).

You can check this post to find the solution.
[WCF NamedPipe CommunicationException - "The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836199/wcf-namedpipe-communicationexception-the-pipe-has-been-ended-109-0x6d)